# Spring boot login page for both SAML and form based authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-saml

I am trying to integrate saml in my spring boot application.
I have no problem to get form based authentication working and saml authentication working but when I try to get both on same application I get stuck with endless redirects

What I am trying to get is a custom login page so that when the user asks for a private resource he gets redirected to the login page. here he finds a form asking for username and password and a button with "DO SAML LOGIN" that when pressed redirects to idp for saml login.

I am using spring boot 3.0.4 (without websecurityconfigureradapter)

this is my security configuration

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

```
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/rs/test/**").permitAll() 
                .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll() 
                .requestMatchers("/webapp/**").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll() 
                .requestMatchers("/rs/csrf/**").authenticated()     
                .anyRequest().authenticated();


        http.cors();

        //THIS WORKS WHEN ALONE
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/webapp/index.html", true);

      //THIS manages the saml2 response and loads the roles from the local database
        OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setResponseAuthenticationConverter(responseToken -> {
            Saml2Authentication authentication = OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.createDefaultResponseAuthenticationConverter().convert(responseToken);
            Assertion assertion = responseToken.getResponse().getAssertions().get(0);
            String username = assertion.getSubject().getNameID().getValue();
            UserDetails userDetails = myUserDetailsService(dataSource).loadUserByUsername(username);
            authentication.setDetails(userDetails);
            if (userDetails.getAuthorities() != null || userDetails.getAuthorities().size() > 0) {
                return new Saml2Authentication((AuthenticatedPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal(), responseToken.getResponse().toString(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
            } else {
                return authentication;
            }
        });

        //THIS WORKS WHEN ALONE
        http.saml2Login(saml2 -> saml2.authenticationManager(new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider))
                .loginPage("/login")
        );

        


    return http.build();
}
```